# [iPhone]How would you design Core Data Object Model for the given below structure

Tags: iphone, core-data

```
  

    JSON As Dictionary 
    {
       headers =     (
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = Name;
            headerText = Name;
            id = Name;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "";
            width = 60;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = BidPrice;
            headerText = Bid;
            id = BidPrice;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Bid Price";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = AskPrice;
            headerText = Ask;
            id = AskPrice;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Ask Price";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = PriceChg;
            headerText = Chg;
            id = PriceChg;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Price Change";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = SSPAsk;
            headerText = SSP;
            id = SSPAsk;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Stripped Spread Offer";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = SSPChgDay;
            headerText = Chg;
            id = SSPChgDay;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Stripped Spread Change";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = PECSAsk;
            headerText = PECS;
            id = PECSAsk;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Par Equivalent CDS Ask";
            width = " 30";
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = PECSChg;
            headerText = Chg;
            id = PECSChg;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Par Equivalent CDS Ask Chg";
            width = " 30";
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = SOLAsk;
            headerText = ZSpd;
            id = SOLAsk;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "SOL Ask";
            width = 30;
        },
                {
            backGroundImageUrl = "";
            dataField = YTMAsk;
            headerText = YTM;
            id = YTMAsk;
            itemRenderer = "";
            toolTip = "Yield To Maturity";
            width = 30;
        }
    );
    values =     (
                {
            assetCellValueLst =             {
                AskColorCode = "#B8D1ED";
                AskPrice = "102.20";
                BidColorCode = "#B8D1ED";
                BidPrice = "102.00";
                Name = "AR Bonar 11";
                PECSAsk = 569;
                PECSChg = "(31)";
                PECSChgColorCode = "#000000";
                PriceChg = "0.00";
                PriceChgColorCode = "#000000";
                SOLAsk = 604;
                SSPAsk = 677;
                SSPChgDay = "+3";
                SSPChgDayColorCode = "#000000";
                YTMAsk = "6.97";
                assetGroupName = Argentina;
                assetId = ARBONAR11;
                iconPath = "images/flag_Argentina.gif";
                updated = false;
            };
            assetId = ARBONAR11;
        },
                {
            assetCellValueLst =             {
                AskColorCode = "#53840f";
                AskPrice = "84.00";
                BidColorCode = "#53840f";
                BidPrice = "83.75";
                Name = "AR Bod 15";
                PECSAsk = 945;
                PECSChg = 14;
                PECSChgColorCode = "#000000";
                PriceChg = "-0.10";
                PriceChgColorCode = "#53840F";
                SOLAsk = 985;
                SSPAsk = 1007;
                SSPChgDay = "+7";
                SSPChgDayColorCode = "#000000";
                YTMAsk = "11.74";
                assetGroupName = Argentina;
                assetId = ARBON15;
                iconPath = "images/flag_Argentina.gif";
                updated = false;
            };
            assetId = ARBON15;
        });
```

Comment: and you want people to read through this json? Why dont u just list the fields in your dictionary..

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322191/how-to-design-object-graph-model

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have two tables there with some obvious field names and types.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am having trouble initializing the NSDictionary inside values. If i have a values : NSManagedObject class. As the dictionary inside can Change according to user prefrences i.e. assetCellValueLst Dictionary can have certain keys or it might not have them at all. @Daniel Sorry just posted it with better formatting